# Functions with Arrays in R

Tags: arrays, r

Let's say I have maximum temperature data for the last 20 years.  My data frame has a column for month, day, year and MAX_C (temperature data).  I want to calculate the mean (and standard deviation, and range) maximum temperature from June 31 of one year to July 1 of the preceding year (i.e. mean max daily temp from July 1, 1991 to June 31, 1992).  Is there an efficient way to do this?

My approach, thus far, has been to create an array:

```
maxt.prev12<-tapply(maxt$MAX_C,INDEX=list(maxt$month,maxt$day,maxt$year),mean)
```

I put mean in as the function as tapply was not producing an array without a function after the INDEX, but mean is not actually calculating anything here.  Then I was thinking about trying to take January through June from one the matrices (i.e. 1992), and July through December from the preceding matrix (i.e. 1991), and then computing the mean.  I'm not entirely sure how to do that part, however, there must be a more efficient way of performing these calculations in R

**EDIT**
Here is a simple sample set of data

```
maxt            
day month   year    MAX_C
1   1       1990    29
1   2       1990    28
1   3       1990    32
1   4       1990    26
1   5       1990    24
1   6       1990    32
1   7       1990    30
1   8       1990    28
1   9       1990    28
1   10      1990    24
1   11      1990    30
1   12      1990    30
1   1       1991    25
1   2       1991    26
1   3       1991    28
1   4       1991    25
1   5       1991    24
1   6       1991    32
1   7       1991    26
1   8       1991    32
1   9       1991    26
1   10      1991    26
1   11      1991    27
1   12      1991    26
1   1       1992    27
1   2       1992    25
1   3       1992    29
1   4       1992    32
1   5       1992    27
1   6       1992    27
1   7       1992    24
1   8       1992    25
1   9       1992    28
1   10      1992    26
1   11      1992    31
1   12      1992    27
```

Comment: sample data would be very helpful. use `dput(myData)`

Comment: `dput` is nice because the person who is answering your post doesn't have to import the data all over again (like making the DATE column into POSIX*).

Comment: sorry to be vague. If your dataset is named `maxt`, then yes run `dput(maxt)` in your R console. Copy the output from that command and paste it into your question. This will allow others to recreate the dataset in our R sessions. To be clear - this will be an exact copy of your dataset, so if it is sensitive data that should not be shared - then make up some dummy data that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an "indicator year" column which was equal to the year if month in July-Dec but equal to year-1 when month in Jan-June.

EDITED month reference in light of the fact it was numeric rather than character:

```
> maxt$year2 <- maxt$year
> maxt[ maxt$month %in% 1:6, "year2"] <- 
+                         maxt[ maxt$month %in% 1:6, "year"] -1
> # month.name is a 12 element constant vector in all versions of R
> # check that it matches the spellings of your months
> 
> mean_by_year <- tapply(maxt$MAX_C, maxt$year2, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
> mean_by_year
    1989     1990     1991     1992 
28.50000 27.50000 27.50000 26.83333
```

If you wanted to change the labels so they reflected the non-calendar year derivation:

```
> names(mean_by_year) <- paste(substr(names(mean_by_year),3,4),
+                       as.character( as.numeric(substr(names(mean_by_year),3,4))+1), 
                               sep="_")
> mean_by_year
   89_90    90_91    91_92    92_93 
28.50000 27.50000 27.50000 26.83333
```

Although I don't think it will be quite right at the millennial turn.